# How to Show a Div when used display:none

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, ajax

I have hidden a `<div>` based on a response from an ajax method using `display: none`. What if I want to show the same `<div>` upon another call to the AJAX method?

I am wondering if `display: none` actually removes the element from DOM because using `display: block` doesn't make the `<div>` visible again. How do I show and hide the same div using the `display` attribute. Here's the code I am using for the AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "Request.aspx/FireEvents",
  data: JSON.stringify({ controlValues: pageControlNamesAndValues }),
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (response) {
    var controlVals = response.d;
    $.each(controlVals, function (index, currentControl) {
      var targetDropDown = document.getElementById(ctrlName);
      console.log('Targetdropdown is ' + targetDropDown);
      if (targetDropDown != null) {
        if (targetDropDown instanceof HTMLDivElement) {
          if (currentControl.ControlName == "LogicChecks") {
            if (currentControl.ControlValue = "hidden") {
              targetDropDown.style.display = 'none';
            } else {
              targetDropDown.style.display = 'block';
            }
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
});
```

The last line (`...style.display ='block';`) doesn't show the `<div>` once it has been hidden.

Comment: Can you confirm the `success` function is called? Can you confirm the element is found? You can use the javascript debugging console (in any major browser) to test lines of code and see if they have any effect on the DOM. `display: none` does not remove elements from the DOM.

Comment: Use jQuery now you have it. `$("#"+ ctrlName).show()` or `$("#"+ ctrlName).hide()` assuming you have ctrlName somewhere (I cannot see it)

Comment: Yes, The success method is always executed. Yes, the element will be found on initial page load. but then based on this ajax response we need to hide and show some div's

Comment: This makes zero sense: `var targetDropDown = document.getElementById(ctrlName);
                if (targetDropDown == null) {
                   targetDropDown = document.getElementById(ctrlName);
                }`

Comment: Also `$("#"+ ctrlName).toggle(currentControl.ControlValue!="hidden")` and `=` is assignment, `==` is test for equality

Comment: No, `display:none` does not remove it from the DOM.

Comment: Actaully I didn't include the change of the `ctrlName` variable to point to the new ID as there's some more logic in changing it but how ever I can assure that the element would be found on the page no matter

Comment: Well IF you have an element in the `targetDropDown` variable, then `targetDropDown.style.display = 'block';` should indeed ensure it is shown, as it essentially sets its inline style (which overrides classes, etc) to `display: block;` … So the question is most likely whether your script ever reaches the line where this happens – have you tried placing a console logging call right before the display is set to block?

Comment: But that is assuming `if(currentControl.ControlValue="hidden")` does what is expected and it does not since it should use == and not =

Comment: @mplungjan: the currentControl is a return object from ajax call of the following format ('ID of the Div' 'its visibility value(hidden/show)') So, if the ajax call returns `(div1,show)` we would  show div with ID div1 and hide if it returns `(div1,hidden)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery to show and hide:

```
$("#"+ ctrlName).show() 
$("#"+ ctrlName).hide()
```

Also use `==` to test for equality; `=` is assignment
This statement is not testing for hidden but assigning hidden

```
if(currentControl.ControlValue="hidden")
```

Lastly

```
var targetDropDown = document.getElementById(ctrlName); 
if (targetDropDown == null) { targetDropDown = 
  document.getElementById(ctrlName); }
```

does not make logical sense

Perhaps this is what you mean

```js
function ProcessEventsActions(pageControlNamesAndValues) {
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "Request.aspx/FireEvents",
      data: JSON.stringify({
        controlValues: pageControlNamesAndValues
      }),
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(response) {
        var controlVals = response.d;
        $.each(controlVals, function(index, currentControl) {
          if (currentControl.ControlName == "LogicChecks") {
            targetDropDown = $("#" + currentControl.controlDiv); // or whatever the name is
            targetDropdown.toggle(currentControl.ControlValue != "hidden"); // show if not hidden
          }
        });
      });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments and demonstrated in Matt's answer, the method for showing / hiding elements is correct, that is

```
element.style.display = "block";
```

Behaves as you would expect, even after it has been hidden by applying `display: none`. Here is an example using jQuery instead (since this *is* a jQuery question):

```js
$("#click1").click(function() { $("#el").hide(); });
$("#click2").click(function() { $("#el").show(); });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="el">Visible</div>
<button id="click1">Click to hide</button>
<button id="click2">Click to show</button>
```

The problem is definitely with the rest of your code. A likely suspect is this line:

```
if (currentControl.ControlValue = "hidden") {
```

If you indeed copied your code directly and this is not a typo, this condition will always evaluate to `true` / a truthy value! And this would cause the problems you are describing, since the code would always hide the element, never showing it again. To fix this, simply replace the line with:

```
if (currentControl.ControlValue == "hidden") {
```

Comment: OP has a hard time understanding jQuery in his own code. And he IS using jQuery thus .show,hide,toggle is more useful in my opinion that ES6 which is not even compatible without Babel

Comment: @mplungjan The demo is for demonstrative purposes only, but yes, I will probably change it to jQuery to avoid confusion.

Comment: @mplungjan I know, but a demonstration to convince OP might be needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of it working. Make sure you are accessing the element correctly.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
#myDIV {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    display:none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click the "Try it" button to set the display property of the DIV element to "block":</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="myDIV">
This is my DIV element.
</div>

<p><b>Note:</b> The element will not take up any space when the display property set to "none".</p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "block";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this an answer to the above question at all?

Comment: This actually shows the div. but I need to get it back once its hidden as well